# How can I use port number in securing web request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have some web application that uses Spring-security and deployed in Tomcat7. In tomcat there are two connectors (8080, 8081). I want to share part of my application and give access to requests like ${ip}:8080/${servercontext}/resource and secure the rest of application by this port, i.e. deny requests like ${ip}:8080/${servercontext}/otherresource. But requests like ${ip}:8081/${servercontext}/otherresource must be accessible (8081 port).

How can I do it ?

Comment: I will expose the application on public domain by 8080 port. Port 8081 I want to use in a private network. And any requests by 8081 port must not be denied.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Spring security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-requires-channel), you can use the `requires-channel` attribute in the `intercept-url` tag :

```
<http>
  <intercept-url pattern="/resource/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="otherresource" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="any"/>
  ...
</http>
```

You can also note that there is an **other** way of doing it (non spring-specific), in your web.xml add the following code :

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection> 
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
```

This will automatically redirect the user to HTTPS (you need to configure your server to support HTTPS, but it seems you already did it)

Comment: It's not what I want. Any requests by 8081 port must not be denied. Please see my comment above. Also your aproach requires manipulation with SSL - certificate, container and so on.